# Cassandra query string length

Tags: cassandra, cql, string-length

How can I get the length of a string in Cassandra?  There don't seem to be any built-in functions to do this for me.

Looking for something like this:

```
SELECT size(myStr) FROM myTable WHERE ...
```

I know this may be possible using user-defined functions, but I'm not sure if I have the appropriate permissions to be able to create functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no inbuilt function for it but you can create `UDF` in Cassandra to find the length of the String column  and then use that `UDF` in your query. Before creating this UDF make sure you have enabled udf property in your `cassandra.yml` file i.e. `enable_user_defined_functions: true`

```
CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS len (input text) 
   CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
   RETURNS int 
   LANGUAGE java AS '
   return input.length();';
```

Then you can use it in your query as,

```
cqlsh:test> SELECT len(event_data) as length from event where id = 1;
```

And you should get output,

```
 length
--------
     14
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make a UDF to do it, but there is none built in cassandra.