# How to check length of text field of Cassandra table

Tags: cassandra, string-length

There is one field 'name' in our Cassandra database whose data type is type 'text'
How do I retrieve the data which has length of the 'name' field greater than some number using Cassandra query.

Comment: Maybe the answers to this question will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674114/cassandra-query-string-length

Answer (score 1):

As was [pointed in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674114/cassandra-query-string-length), it's easy to add the user-defined function, and use it to retrieve the length of the text field, but the catch is that you can't use the user-defined function in the WHERE condition (see [CASSANDRA-8488](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8488)).

Even if it was possible, if you only have this as condition - that's a bad query for Cassandra, as it will need to go through all data in the database, and filter them out.  For such tasks, usually things like, Spark are used - you can read data via [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/), and apply necessary filtering conditions.  But this will involve reading all of the data from database, and then performing the filtering - this would be quite slower than normal CQL queries, but at least automatically parallelized.